# cloundfront compress doesn't seem to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured cloudfront to `Compress Objects Automatically`. The origin server is s3 bucket. I uploaded a file to s3 through cloudfront then send a GET request to the file. But the return content-type is not gzip. Below is the request I sent and you can see the response content type is `application/octet-stream`. I have added  `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the header but why can't it return a compressed content?

```
$ curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://dnruqi0psnxg6.cloudfront.net/images/cells/dc0c2f15-065b-4f3c-a4d6-81c3b09a163f.png
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 142317
date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 22:58:49 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 22:58:49 GMT
etag: "c6d54353c861d0145e10b1abdcb2976c"
x-amz-version-id: jgFwqD.F6lzvjbgcjfO.E6KK3IdHttaR
accept-ranges: bytes
server: AmazonS3
age: 29
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: MTgwzb8KZinic50msfORINK2pSHW8QCOv82ur0Lq3-jH3WH_8prvow==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the objects meet the following criteria from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html):

> - The file must be of a type that CloudFront compresses.
> - The file size must be between 1,000 and 10,000,000 bytes.
> - The response must include a Content-Length header so CloudFront can determine whether the size of the file is in the range that CloudFront
>     compresses. If the Content-Length header is missing, CloudFront won't
>     compress the file.
> - The response must not include a Content-Encoding header.

See the list of [types of files that CloudFront can compress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types).

In this case the problem appears to be that `application/octet-stream` is not compressible by CloudFront.

Comment: I upload an image to cloudfront but the content-type is `application/octet-stream`. Does this mean cloudfront doesn't support compressing images?

Comment: Yes. Generally speaking you do not want to gzip images, as the image formats themselves handle compressing the data.

Comment: @ZhaoYi "image compression" is not compression in this same sense. CloudFront's "compress objects automatically" feature applies *reversible* gzip compression that allows the browser to reconstruct the original object byte-for-byte. Image compression is almost always a form of non-reversible *data reduction* which eliminates theoretically redundant data to make file sizes smaller, but loses quality and/or detail in a way that it can't be fully reconstructed but that is considered an acceptable tradeoff of quality for size/speed. Appropriate ratios & algorithms are subjective, nothing is free.